# Style doesn't apply in NextJS with TailwindCSS

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I've be trying to style a component using TailwindCSS but the style doesn't apply.

Here's the code:

```js
import Image from 'next/image';

function Header() {
    return (
        <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 grid grid-cols-3 bg-red-500">
            {/* Left */}
            <div className="relative flex items-center h-10 cursor-pointer my-auto">
                <Image src="https://links.papareact.com/qd3" 
                       layout="fill" 
                       objectFit="contain"
                       objectPosition="left"
                />
            </div>

            {/* Middle */}
            <div>

            </div>

            {/* Right */}
            <div>

            </div>


        </header>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

I was reading the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration) and found that I need to specify some informations in a file called tailwind.config.js, so I did this:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: also to the content config to give full scope:`content:['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}','./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add this in styles/global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

and also import the global.css in pages/_app.js

```
 import "../styles/global.css"; 

 function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 return (
    <Component {...pageProps} /> 
  );
 }
export default MyApp;
```

and also create `postcss.config.js` in root of you application and insert this code

```
  module.exports = {
    plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
   autoprefixer: {},
  },
 }
```